# Call Email intent by getting data from sub strings?

Tags: android, string

I am making QR code scan app. When i scan the QR Code for Email, I get the result i.e. given below,

```
String data = MATMSG:TO:abc@hotmail.com;SUB:email subject;BODY:email body;;
```

For getting code type i.e. MATMSG in string above i am doing this,

```
String[] parts = scanData.split(":");
qrCodeType = parts[0];
```

I want to make 3 strings from the data string like,

```
String to = abc@hotmail.com;
String subject = email subject;
String body = email body;
```

How can i use string functions to do this? Notice **colons** and **semicolons** in String data

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I was facing some problem because i am getting part[0] separately. I have edited the question, review it again

Comment: the first split, you have to use ';' (semicolon) in order to separate the 3 parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String[] items = data.split(";");

String to = items[0].split(":")[2];
String subject = items[1].split(":")[1];
String body = items[2].split(":")[1];
```

Hope it helps